# No GUI to login, but can access remotely

Tags: 18.04, login, gui, remote-login

We have a problem with some of our desktops, and I do not know what to do about it. 
The OS is Ubuntu 18.04:

```
5.3.0-51-generic #44~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 23 14:27:18 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

We only used our desktops remotely over a period of 2 months, during quarantine, and after going back to office we lost the GUI for the normal login to use the Ubuntu systems.

The only thing that we see is this screen:

[image]

It happened for all the systems in one of our offices.
We can still access the machines remotely, albeit with an increased login time.

Please let me know what further information I should send here to help diagnose the problem without reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: That looks like a failure to start a display server? can you get to a terminal on the machine (not remote?)

Comment: @JacobSchneider, Thank you. you mean directly boot to terminal? I have not tried. I am out of office right now  and I can only access remotely if I can post something here.

Comment: > Boot to terminal
Yes, I meant that. I had accidentally uninstalled all of my greeters for my system. at that point I had to figure out how to boot to a terminal and reinstall them. next time you get the chance, see if you can start the GUI through the terminal

Comment: @JacobSchneider, thank you, I will try to see if it can solve our problem.

Comment: keep me posted, I'd be interested to know if that was the issue

Comment: Sure! thank you.

Comment: @muru, Thank you for the edit.